# is it possible to have MySQL Active-Active Clustering with DRBD?

Tags: mysql, drbd, mysql-cluster

we use MySQL 5.6 InnoDB engine for our database purpose.
currently we have a single instance of it , but as our application is growing , we  want to have our database in cluster mode. now what we have done till now :

We tried MySQL NDB cluster 7.3.1 (Lab version ): but we still face problems with foreign keys and it doesn't seems to be reliable.so we tried next option.

we tried mysql active/passive clustering with DRBD, pacemaker and corosync : everything works fine on two nodes.

now we want to do Mysql active-active clustering , even after a lot of google i am unble to find any information on it , can we do it with DRBD or there is some other way to do it.

please help !!!!!

Comment: Mysql Replication may help you.

Comment: Omesh, i want active/active clustering , may be i'll require a load-balancer but i don't know how to use that. and this replication is i think for active passive.

Comment: @ChetanSharma Hi, did you found any solution for this? If yes, can please share it. I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Galera Cluster for MySQL or (based on that) the Percona XtraDB Cluster.

http://codership.com/content/using-galera-cluster

http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster

Both provide multi node active mysql server (only for innodb) with easy setup.

Comment: hi ralph , thanks for your answer.MySQL NDB CLuster 7.3.2 is now available and i am going with it, i'll also explore options provided by you

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication